# Error while making a directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting error while making the following directory in powershell

```
mkdir bin NAME tests docs
```

Here is the error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'NAME'
```

Comment: What are you trying to create? Mkdir is an alias for New-Item. Type Help New-Item -Detailed for how to use this command

Comment: Did you try to create several dirs at once or do you expect a new directory "bin NAME tests docs"?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new directory with PowerShell you should be using `new-item`

An example:

`New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "NAME\test\docs" -ItemType "directory"`

Additional documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mkdir bin NAME tests docs
> ```

instead, use comma separated name

```
mkdir bin, NAME, tests, docs
```

Comment: Did you try your suggested code? Please read output from `Get-Command mkdir | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition`…